Copy Files From Azure VM To Home Mac
I have a VM in Azure. And a mac at home. I am currently SSHed into my Azure VM from my Mac. I am trying to copy a file from my Azure VM to my home Mac. And the command fails.
sudo scp azure/file/path /Users/[user]/Downloads

I'm getting this error:

cp: cannot create regular file '/Users/[user]/Downloads': No such file or directory

I don't understand why its not copying the file. Based on the error it seems to think I'm trying to copy the file onto the VM at that path, which doesn't exist on that VM. Only on my home Mac.
Is this not the right command for a simple file copy?

Your shell environment on the Azure VM won't have any knowledge about the location that you have SSH'd from. The best option here would be to run a SCP command from your Mac targeting the path on the remote VM. You'll need to use the @: syntax to target the path on your VM.
